# SVG in console application (C#)

Tags: c#, svg, console-application

Is it possible to show an SVG Image in console application in C#? Without WPF or Windows Forms, just a normal console application and if yes, how? I am new in C# so I still need to learn a bit.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mind if it's rendered as ASCII art?

Comment: Graphics and console don't mix. Yopu will need to open a Winforms or WPF window. Or write your own SVG2AsciiArt converter.

Comment: @Llama  need the orginal SVG Image looking.

Comment: No, you're not able to show the original SVG image in the text console.

Comment: @PalleDue Oh I understand.

Comment: @AKX  Okay.  Thanks guys!